# How do I get the address of the connected wallet with @walletconnect/react-native-dapp?

Tags: react-native, blockchain, ethereum, wallet, wallet-connect

I need to get the addres of metamask using @walletconnect/react-native-dapp

Comment: Show your code and what you've tried already.

Answer (score 2):

Below is sample code to fetch wallet address:

```
import { useWalletConnect } from "@walletconnect/react-native-dapp";

export default function fetchWalletAddress() {
  const connector = useWalletConnect();
  const walletAddress= connector.accounts[0]
}
```

https://docs.walletconnect.com/quick-start/dapps/react-native